# failed to link image to html code ive used diff code editors

Tags: image, path, hyperlink

I've failed to link anything to my html files even stylesheets, JavaScript files or even images. Yes, I've used the right file path I've even used different code editors.

I've used the right file path and even different code editors, but it won't show the image on the websites or even linking to JavaScript files or CSS files.[[[image of  code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8u2m.png)][image of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkPQY.png)